# Solve matrix equation with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following matrices $A, B$ with parameter $k ∈ \Bbb R$:
\begin{equation}
A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    2k & k+1 & 0\\
    1 & k & 1\\
    k^2 &-1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    k & 0 & 4\\
    1 & 0 & k\\
    1 & k-1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Calculate matrix $X$ that verifies the following equation:

\begin{equation}
2k^2(A + X - B) + k^2(B-X)-2k^2A= O
\end{equation}

where $O$ is the $3 \times 3$ null matrix.

If I solve the equation I find that
\begin{equation}
X=B
\end{equation}
hence for any values of $k$ as long as the above is true then I get the null matrix, but that seems odd. Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion? Which steps did you take?

Comment: @VanBaffo well solving the equation:
\begin{equation}
2k^2A+2k^2X-2k^2B+k^2B-Xk^2-2k^2A=O
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k^2X-k^2B=O
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k^2X=-k^2B
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
X=B
\end{equation}

I edited the question as it was written +B instead of -B sorry

Comment: Well, then you have solved the problem I guess

Comment: @VanBaffo so is it correct to say that no matter what value of k I pick then as long as X = B, I obtain the null matrix?

Comment: If $k=0$ then, by your calculation, any $X$ will do the work.

Comment: It seems so indeed

Comment: @Flea, You've done the hard part of solving the equation. It's then easy to verify by simply substituting $X = B$ back into the original equation! I.e.,
$$
2k^2(A + B - B) + k^2(B-B)-2k^2A \\= 2k^2A - 2k^2A \\= 0
$$
which is indeed obviously true for any value of $k$.

Comment: Moreover, it didn't matter what $A$ and $B$ were.